# Any tips for parking in Nice, France to save money?

Tags: budget, france, automobiles, nice

Free parking in old town is super hard to find and parking otherwise is very expensive. Do travelers have tips to save money on parking. Are there parking places outside old town that are free to park from where you can either take public transportation or walk back.

Comment: You always can do street parking near a tram stop; you just have to avoid the "Payant" spaces.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the recommend way is Park & Ride via the tram. The term you are looking for is [Relais Parcazur](http://www.lignesdazur.com/presentation/?rub_code=12), and there's lots of information available on it on the [Lignes d'Azur site](http://www.lignesdazur.com/presentation/?rub_code=12). (Click the english flag in the top right to get it into English if the page shows in French)

There are carparks designed for this at the Pont Michel, Vauban, Henri Sappia, Palais des Expositions and Saint-Augustin tram stops.

1 day's parking and a return tram ticket is currently €3, 1 day's parking an unlimited tram use is €5.

Note that the car parks are only to be used for the day, and there's a large fine if you leave your car there overnight

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are there any places to park overnight?

Comment: Not something I know about, sorry!